# Troubleshooting DependencyProperty data binding

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

My apologies for a question this long.  Normally I try to avoid asking other folks do my debugging for me, but I'm into my second day on this problem, and I'm admitting I need some help.

I have a Silverlight AudioVisualizer user control which has a FrameSource dependency property, defined like so:

```
    public short[] FrameSource
    {
        get { return (short[])GetValue(FrameSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FrameSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FrameSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FrameSource", typeof(short[]), typeof(AudioVisualizer), new PropertyMetadata(OnFrameSourceChanged));

    private static void OnFrameSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            short[] source = e.NewValue as short[];
            AudioVisualizer instance = d as AudioVisualizer;
            if (source != null && source.Length > 0 && instance != null)
            {
                instance.RenderVisualization(source);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            ClientLogger.LogDebugMessage(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I'd like the source of this property to be a short[] array exposed by an AudioStatistics class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged, like so:

```
private short[] latestFrame;
public Array LatestFrame
{
    get
    {
        return latestFrame;
    }
    set
    {
        if (++FrameCount % ReportingInterval == 0 && value != null)
        {
            if (latestFrame == null || Buffer.ByteLength(latestFrame) != Buffer.ByteLength(latestFrame))
            {
                latestFrame = new short[Buffer.ByteLength(value) / sizeof(short)];
            }
            Buffer.BlockCopy(value, 0, latestFrame, 0, Buffer.ByteLength(value));
            OnPropertyChanged("LatestFrame");
        }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                    }
                });
}
```

(Four minor but I believe unrelated oddities about the code above: (1) I'm only sending a small subset of the audio frames to the audio visualizer, to keep the CPU load to a minimum; (2) the audio processing always takes place on a background thread, so I need to marshal the PropertyChanged event onto the UI thread; (3) to minimize GC issues, I'm copying the data into a buffer during the assignment, rather than just assigning a new reference; (4) I'm exposing the short[] latestFrame field as an Array property rather than a short[], because sometimes the data comes in as a byte[] array representing shorts, and sometimes a short[] array, but which it is doesn't matter, because of #3.  I also think this code is working correctly, because the other bindings are working correctly -- see below. Just including for completeness.)

I've setup the bindings like this:

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="audioVisualizersListBox"  >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <sdk:Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                    <av:AudioVisualizer FrameSource="{Binding LatestFrame, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}"  Margin="4" Height="200" Width="300" VolumeFactor="3" />
                    <sdk:Label Content="{Binding LatestFrame, Converter={StaticResource debugShortsToStringConverter}}" />
                    <sdk:Label Content="{Binding FrameCount, StringFormat='Frames: {0}'}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The ItemsControl is bound to an ObservableCollection property of a MediaController class:

```
    AudioStatistics speakerStatistics = new AudioStatistics("Sent to Speaker");
    AudioStatistics microphoneStatistics = new AudioStatistics("Received from Microphone");
    AudioStatistics cancelledStatistics = new AudioStatistics("Echo Cancelled");
    AudioStats = new ObservableCollection<AudioStatistics>();
    AudioStats.Add(speakerStatistics);
    AudioStats.Add(microphoneStatistics);
    AudioStats.Add(cancelledStatistics);
```

The actual assignment of the DataContext takes place in the code-behind of my main form, and just looks like what you'd expect:

```
audioVisualizersListBox.ItemsSource = mediaController.AudioStats;
```

All the bindings except for the AudioVisualizer.FrameSource binding are working correctly.  For instance, every time the source object's LatestFrame property changes, the label with the debugShortsToStringConverter converter updates, and every time the FrameCount changes, the label bound to the FrameCount property also changes.

The problem is that in my AudioVisualizer control, the OnFrameSourceChanged callback only gets called twice.  After those two calls, it never gets called again.  It's sort of like the "FrameSource" dependency property doesn't properly register for the INotifyPropertyChanged notifications.  I suppose I could register for them manually myself somehow in the OnFrameSourceChanged method, but I'd need to be mucking about with reflection and what-not, and that doesn't seem right.

One last datapoint: at some point *after* I get a correct frame submitted to the FrameSource DependencyProperty, I get this error in the VS debug window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'LatestFrame' property not found on 'Alanta.Client.Controls.AudioVisualizer.AudioVisualizer' 'Alanta.Client.Controls.AudioVisualizer.AudioVisualizer' (HashCode=63535124). BindingExpression: Path='LatestFrame' DataItem='Alanta.Client.Controls.AudioVisualizer.AudioVisualizer' (HashCode=63535124); target element is 'Alanta.Client.Controls.AudioVisualizer.AudioVisualizer' (Name=''); target property is 'FrameSource' (type 'System.Int16[]')..

That's a very odd error message, because it seems to indicate that it's trying to bind to the AudioVisualizer.LatestFrame property, which of course doesn't exist.  The AudioStatistics class has a LatestFrame property, but the Audiovisualizer class only has a FrameSource property.  Very confusing, but I've double-checked my bindings (and triple-checked), and they seem to be defined correctly.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?  This is my first time trying to implement databinding with my own dependency property, so quite possibly I'm missing something obvious.

(11/9/10 - Edited to add more code that I'd left out the first time, because it was already too long.)

Comment: It would make sense for you to include the code from your `AudioStatistics` class showing how the value of `LatestFrame` is modified and goes about invoking `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: BTW, the label bound to `LatestFrame` is that working?

Comment: I've added the code you requested in the question above.  And yes, all the other bindings seem to be working correctly.  Does it seems like I'm using the DependencyProperty.Register() method correctly?  That's the part I haven't been able to find good documentation on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  I was making two mistakes, one from being stupid, one from being too clever by half.

(1) Somewhere in the bowels of the AudioVisualizer code-behind (which I'd originally borrowed from somewhere else), it was reassigning its DataContext to itself.  That was the source of the BindingExpression error up above.

(2) Apparently the DependencyProperty subsystem tries to be smart about which INotifyPropertyChanged events it forwards on to its dependency properties. Among other things, it seems to check whether the object reference is actually pointing to a new object.  If it's not, it doesn't bother to call the PropertyChangedCallback delegate.  So when I was updating the array by copying new data into it, rather than changing the reference, it didn't look to the DependencyProperty subsystem like anything had changed, and hence it wasn't forwarding on the event.